# Bash parallization using & stored in a variable

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script and intend to loop over some files, allowing for parallel execution of the commands by executing the single commands in the background (&). Furthermore I want to use a command line option, that enables parallelization/background execution. In a first case this has been working out using eval.

```
if [ ! -z $parallelization ]
then
  PARALLEL='&'
else
  PARALLEL=''
fi

...

for file in list_of_files
do
  # eval needed to turn $PARALLE into &
  eval command $file $PARALLEL
done
```

With a singel command that's been working nicely so far. The problem starts when I have to execute various commands within the loop and want to put all of them into the background. The following code is not working:

```
for file in list_of_files
do
  eval {
  # piping is not working with command_1 and 2
  command_1 $file > intermediateFile
  command_2 intermediateFile > result
  rm intermediateFile;
  } $PARALLEL
done
```

But this doesn't work at all:

```
./variant_calling.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./variant_calling.sh: line 20: `               } ${PARALLEL}'
```

Simply removing eval doesn't work either:

```
./variant_calling.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `${PARALLEL}'
./variant_calling.sh: line 20: `               } ${PARALLEL}'
```

What works is:

```
for file in list_of_files
do
  {
  # piping is not working with command_1 and 2
  command_1 $file > intermediateFile
  command_2 intermediateFile > result
  rm intermediateFile;
  } &
done
```

But here the parallelization is always enabled. So is there a way to still use the variable $PARALLEL containing the & if background execution is desired?

Any help to solve this probleme will be highly appreciated!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try putting your command_1 and command_2 inside a function, then call that function using your eval func $PARALLEL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `eval` for this at all, as it introduces a security vulnerability if you don't have strict control over the value of `$file` in each case. Instead, just be explicit at the use site:

```
for file in ...; do
    if [ -n "$parallelization" ]; then
        command "$file" &
    else
        command "$file"
    fi
done
```

---

The problem with your initial attempt is that `eval` doesn't take a command group as an argument. The parser sees 4 simple commands

1. `eval {`
2. `command_1 $file > intermediateFile`
3. `command_2 intermediateFile > result`
4. `rm intermediateFile;`

followed by `}`, which cannot occur in the command position. It's not paired with the `{` in the first command it recognized. (And remember, this is just the *parsing* process for the `for` loop; the shell hasn't gotten as far as actually *running* the `eval` command to find out that `{` is not a defined command.)

Instead, you would need to pass the command group as a *single* string argument:

eval "{
  command_1 $file > intermediateFile
  command_2 intermediateFile > result
  rm intermediateFile;
  } $PARALLEL"

which still has the security issue I mentioned above. The contents of `$file` are not treated as a single parameter; it's an arbitrary fragment of code incorporated in to the string that `eval` will parse and execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused due to the command not being wrapped in quotes. The following works on my laptop.

```sh
$ PARALLEL='&'
$ eval "( for i in {0..2}; do sleep 1 && echo -en \"\rWaiting \$i seconds\"; done; echo -e '\nOK'; )" $PARALLEL
Waiting 2 seconds 
OK
```

But, unless you have to combine commands dynamically, you're better of creating a function.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
PARALLEL='&'
function mytest {
    for i in {0..2}; do
        sleep 1
        echo -en "\rWaiting $i seconds";
    done; 
    echo -e '\nOK';
}

for x in {0..3}; do
    eval mytest $PARALLEL
done
exit $?
```

Output of script:

```
$time ./parallel.sh
Waiting 2 seconds
OK
Waiting 2 seconds
OK

OK
Waiting 2 seconds
OK
DERP

real    0m3.016s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: Your function causes each job to be run *serially* in a single background process, rather than the jobs themselves running in parallel with each other.

Comment: No it doesn't, but I understand the confusion. I'll update it.

Comment: Ah, `mytest` is the job, not the wrapper around all the jobs. The two separate loops threw me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your answers!

With my very specific problem I'll probably have to use a combination of all of them. I had loved using eval and not using an function. But I see the point of not using eval due to security reasons.
Still I tried using a function with eval, which acutally did do the trick:

```
combinedCommands (){
  command_1 $1 > tempFile
  command_2 tempFile > result
  rm tempFile
}

for file in list_of_files
do
  eval combinedCommands $file $PARALLEL
done
```

But as I have to use a function anyways I'd end up with something like this:

```
combinedCommands (){
  command_1 $1 > tempFile
  command_2 tempFile > result
  rm tempFile
}

for file in list_of_files
do
  if [ -n parallel_enabled ]
  then 
    combinedCommands $file &
  else
    combinedCommands $file
  fi
done
```

Again may Thanks!

---

I still wanted to make my initial idea work - and if it's only for the sake of solving it. And actually in the end it turned out to be quite easy. The inner block of code just hast to be surrounded by ticks.

```
PARALLEL="&"
...
for file in list_of_files
do
  eval '{
  command_1 $file > tempFile
  command_2 tempFile > result
  rm tempFile;
  }' ${PARALLEL}
done
```

I hope this helps, just in case somebody might need it.